# breezejs with webapi not returning child entities when I use expand

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I’m using WebAPI V4.0.30506.0 (this should be the stable version) with BreezeJs 1.3.5 and for some reason I don’t get child entities when I use the expand keyword.  How can I get the child entities?

Here’s a cut down version of my datamodel.

```
public class Policy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int ModelYear { get; set; }
    public virtual Policy Policy { get; set; }
}
```

Here’s what my get looks like:

```
    var getPolicies = function (policyObservable, getFromServer) {
        if (!getFromServer) {
            var pLocal = getLocal('Policies', 'policyNumber');
            if (pLocal.length > 0 ){
            policyObservable(pLocal);
            return Q.resolve();
            }
        }

         var query = EntityQuery.from('Policies')
            .expand("Vehicles");

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        // handle the ajax callback
        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (policyObservable) {
        // I pause here in Chrome
                policyObservable(data.results);
            }
            log('retrieved policy!', data, true);
        }
    };
```

When I look at the data.results in querySucceeded in Chrome I see an array of Policies but there are no child vehicles.   When I check in the network tab I see it calling:

```
http://localhost/breeze/breeze/Policies?$expand=Vehicles
```

And there are Vehicles in the results.

Here’s a snippet of what I get back:

[
{
"$id": "1",
"$type": "Eclipse.Model.Policy, Eclipse.Model",
"Id": 1,
"PolicyNumber": "PHHOAP00",
"Vehicles": [
{
"$id": "2",
"$type": "Eclipse.Model.Vehicle, Eclipse.Model",
"Id": 1,
"Manufacturer": "ac,",
"Model": "In",
"ModelYear": 2006,
"Policy": {
"$ref": "1"
},...

edit:
I'm not sure if it's related or not but when I type the following in the console I get blank arrays.

```
console.log(data.results[0].entityAspect._entityKey.entityType.navigationProperties)
console.log(data.results[0].entityAspect._entityKey.entityType.foreignKeyProperties)
```

Comment: When you store the results in an observableArray and console.log(ko.observableArray()); there is no navigation property of Vehicles that you can expand in the console?  Or there are no entities in that navigation property?

Comment: No.  I get 4 objects (expected.  it's an array of observables) when I drill down into the each one they only have properties for themselves and not vehicles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maleki,
Have you tried adding a ForeignKey to the Policy in Vehicle? Breeze will need the FK to resolve the navigation between entities and this is most likely what's causing the problem.

Comment: You're correct.  Breeze now requires that foreign keys be explicitly defined.  1.3.4 doesn't require this.  Unfortunately refactoring my code-first datamodel will take several hours (it breaks seeding).

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to the 1.3.4 version of breeze.debug.js fixed the issue.

In my case it appears that in 1.3.5 OData $expand doesn't map properly to the data.results.